# Does ag-grid support server-side filtering on .netcore

Tags: .net, angular, ag-grid

I am trying to evaluate using grids for my angular 8 client that support server-side filtering on .Netcore. I am currently using DevExpress and want to move away from it since I feel there are better tools in the market.
I am seen too much of markup being generated with them. I was contemplating to use ag-grid but dont think they support server-side validation on .net core. Does anybody have idea about ag-grid. I tried searching the net
but couldnt find an appropriate example. Has anybody used any other grid , which is better that devexpress grid. The reason why i am looking for server-side filtering is it is indeed better and far more effecient than 
doing it client side

Answer (score 0):

Below row models of [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) supports server side filtering.

- [Server side row model](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-server-side-model/)
- [Infinite row model](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/)

#### TLDR;

After applying filter, `getRows` (which you are supposed to implement) method of `dataSource` gets called, along with the required parameters like `startRow`, `filterModel`, `sortModel`, etc. - which you can pass on and apply filter at server.

---

Now, your question: ***Does ag-grid support server-side filtering on .netcore***

It doesn't matter which framework you are using at server. You can use .net, .net core, Java, Node, python, or any name add in the list.

The grid should receive `JSON` array. That's it.

Comment: I have seen the first link before. Where does it say it supports .Net. Dev-Express , Kendo has extensions for .net that provide server-side filtering

Comment: [tag:ag-grid] is a client side JavaScript library. Independent of you server side technology.